# Sorting a list of dictionary key objects with custom comparison function in Python

Tags: python, c++, dictionary

I'm porting some code from C++ to Python that relies upon the C++ ordering of keys in the map using custom compare functions.  I has assumed I could simply use a Python dictionary and then use sorted() on the keys using an equivalent function as a key= to sorted().  However, no matter how I try, the keys get traversed in a different order in Python.

The C++ code is some random implementation of gSpan I found on gitub available [here](https://github.com/Jokeren/DataMining-gSpan). See ProjectionMap and struct dfs_code_t in src/gspan.h and src/graph.h .

My simplified python code is below, including a direct copy of two of the comparison functions from the C++ code:

```
dfs_code = collections.namedtuple('dfs_code',
            ['fromn','to','from_label','edge_label','to_label'])

def dfs_code_compare(a, b):
    if a.from_label != b.from_label:
        return a.from_label < b.from_label
    else:
        if a.edge_label != b.edge_label:
            return a.edge_label < b.edge_label
        else:
            return a.to_label < b.to_label

def dfs_code_backward_compare(a, b):
    if a.to != b.to:
        return a.to < b.to
    else:
        return a.edge_label < b.edge_label

# code that fills in a dictionary called pm

for pm in sorted(projection_map, key=functools.cmp_to_key(dfs_code_compare)):
        print pm
```

The python code above produces the following ordering:

```
dfs_code(fromn=0, to=1, from_label=1, edge_label=0, to_label=3)
dfs_code(fromn=0, to=1, from_label=2, edge_label=3, to_label=2)
dfs_code(fromn=0, to=1, from_label=1, edge_label=3, to_label=3)
dfs_code(fromn=0, to=1, from_label=1, edge_label=1, to_label=2)
dfs_code(fromn=0, to=1, from_label=2, edge_label=1, to_label=3)
....
```

Which is a) different from the C++ code, and b) not at all what I'd expect from the comparison function (I'd expect all the from_labels of 1 to be grouped together at the front, for example).  Any ideas? Is it related to functools.cmp_to_key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python, compare functions must return a negative, positive, or zero value indicating whether the first element is less than, greater than, or equal to the second. Since python's < operator returns a bool, your problem is coming from python converting False to 0 and assuming that those values are equal.

You could rewrite the compare functions to use this convention, but it might be easier to write key functions instead.

For example, dfs_code_compare could be converted to this key function:

```
def dfs_code_key(pm):
    return (pm.from_label, pm.edge_label, pm.to_label)
```

and used like this:

```
for pm in sorted(projection_map, key=dfs_code_key):
    pm
```

Comment: Bah! I knew it was something obvious! You're right of course, I completely missed that.